# How to convert UTC datetime stamp to Date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I am trying to convert my  datetime column in a DataFrame  from this `

```
  2021-11-10 00:00:00 UTC
```

`to just this`2021-11-10 `  .

I have tried using this `df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"].dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S UTC')).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')` but I keep getting this error : `

```
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

`
Please someone should come to my rescue.

I have tried

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"].dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S UTC')).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

and I was getting this arror: `

```
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

`

Comment: Parentheses aren't lined up properly, try: `df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Answer (score 2):

To convert a datetime column in a DataFrame from the format "2021-11-10 00:00:00 UTC" to the format "2021-11-10", you can use the `pd.to_datetime` function and the `dt.strftime` method.

I created an example dataframe (from a python dict) for this purpose.

The example looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create the dictionary
data = {'id': [1, 2, 3],
        'name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'],
        'datetime': ['2021-11-10 00:00:00', 
            '2021-11-11 00:00:00', '2021-11-12 00:00:00']}

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert the 'datetime' column to datetime type
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

# Extract the date and convert it to string
df['date'] = df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# Drop the original 'datetime' column (optional)
df = df.drop(columns=['datetime'])

# Display the DataFrame
print(df)
```

The result looks like this:

```
   id     name        date
0   1    Alice  2021-11-10
1   2      Bob  2021-11-11
2   3  Charlie  2021-11-12
```

Comment: You are welcome, if the answer is helpful please accept as the given answer as it will help other users too.